# pandas groupby ngroup() returning -1

Tags: python, pandas

I do not understand how pandas groupby ngroup works.

on the documentation I can read

> Number each group from 0 to the number of groups - 1.

However when I run the following code

```py
granularity = [
    "domain",
    "channel",
    "app_id",
    "section_id",
    "country_id",
]

df["id"] = df.groupby(granularity).ngroups()
```

I get plenty of -1. How come?

Comment: Post full df please.

Comment: code does not work, please post https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example